# How do I get the screen dimensions before init()?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a small game in swift and want to make my player move across 3 fixed points on the screen.
I created an array to store the values in which I calculate in the init function, but the compiler doesn't agree with me not declaring the array before super.init(). Here's what I have

```
//properties
var player:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var playerPos = 1
var legalPositions: [CGFloat]


override init(size:CGSize)
{
    super.init(size: size)


    legalPositions[0] = self.frame.width/4
    legalPositions[0] = self.frame.width/2
    legalPositions[0] = self.frame.width/0.5

}
```

When I try to build it I get the error

GameScene.swift:31:9: Property 'self.legalPositions' not initialized at super.init call

Is there a way to initialize the property before calling the init function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a good use case for [Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_491). Basically you'd define `legalPositions` as `[CGFloat]!` which will default it to `nil`.  Then you can set it **after** your call to `super.init(size: size)`.

Since it's implicitly unwrapped, you don't have to worry about unwrapping it with optional binding or forced unwrapping each time you use it. And, since you're always setting it in your `init` method, you don't have to worry about it being `nil` and causing a crash.

```
//properties
var player:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var playerPos = 1
var legalPositions: [CGFloat]!


override init(size:CGSize)
{
    super.init(size: size)


    legalPositions[0] = self.frame.width/4
    legalPositions[0] = self.frame.width/2
    legalPositions[0] = self.frame.width/0.5

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a dummy value that gets overwritten in the initializer:

```
var legalPositions: [CGFloat] = [0]
```

That way, the `legalPositions` array is initialized before you're calling the base class initializer. Swift's two-phase initialization requires this process in order to be able to guarantee that all properties are initialized after creating a new instance of a class.

The benefit of this approach is that **there's no need for implicitly unwrapped optionals**. They open up the possibility for `nil` values being set, which is not what you want.

Note that the first two assignments in your snippet are unnecessary since the third one will overwrite the value of the first item of the `legalPositions` array anyway.